# Temp Procedure Not giving Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a temporary procedure in SQL Server but when I am trying to execute it, it worls fine except for output parameter.
Output prarameter is not being able to get the output from SP. 
I am not sure why this is occuring.

```
Alter Procedure #AgeDifference
@DOB date,
@output nvarchar(500) Out
AS
Begin
Declare @tempdate date,@year int,@month int,@day int
Set @tempdate=@DOB

Select @year=DateDiff(Year,@tempdate,Getdate())-
   CASE
    WHEN DatePart(Month,@tempdate)>DatePart(Month,Getdate()) 
    OR ( DatePart(Month,@tempdate)=DatePart(Month,Getdate()) AND 
DatePart(Day,@tempdate)>DatePart(Day,Getdate()))
    THEN 1
    Else 0
   END


Set @tempdate=DateAdd(Year,@year,@tempdate)


Select @month=DateDiff(Month,@tempdate,Getdate())-
   CASE
    WHEN DatePart(Day,@tempdate)>DatePart(Day,Getdate()) 
    THEN 1
    Else 0
   END


Set @tempdate=DateAdd(Month,@month,@tempdate)

Select @day=DateDiff(Day,@tempdate,Getdate())

Set @output= 'The difference is '+CAST(@year as nvarchar(10))+ ' Years '+CAST(@month as nvarchar(10))+ ' Months '
  +CAST(@day as nvarchar(10)) +' Days '

print @output
End


Declare @out nvarchar(100)
EXEC #AgeDifference '27/04/1994',@out
print @out
```

Comment: You have to declare the parameter as `out` both where it's *declared* and when the procedure is *invoked* with `exec`.

Comment: Thanks , it worked just fine. Stupid of me to miss that.

Answer (score 1):

Add `OUT` with output parameter too. Change second last line of your code to -

```
EXEC #AgeDifference '27/04/1994',@out OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Please execute with proper date format. it succeed with below thread for me.

 `Declare @out nvarchar(100)
 EXEC #AgeDifference '2018-04-27',@out
 PRINT @out`